# Include arrows in text file read by \verbinput

Tags: verbatim

I have the following tex program:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sverb}

\begin{document}
\verbinput{arrowfile.txt}
\end{document}
```

arrowfile.txt:

```
longest_chain ← 0
```

The arrow is not displayed: it renders as `longest_chain  0`.
How do I display arrows from a plaintext file read in with \verbinput?

EDIT: 
Adding the lines

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

solves the problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX SE! Could you provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your files are UTF-8 encoded, it suffices to load `textcomp`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{arrowfile.txt}
longest_chain ← 0
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{sverb}

\begin{document}

\verbinput{arrowfile.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Important note

The line

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

can be omitted if one is running LaTeX version 2018-04-01 or later. With earlier versions, the code above should be

```
\begin{filecontents*}{arrowfile.txt}
longest_chain ← 0
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{sverb}

\begin{document}

\verbinput{arrowfile.txt}

\end{document}
```

I recommend updating.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Both files are utf8 encoded. I had to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in order to make it work.

Comment: Using this exact code leaves me with the same problem.

Comment: @Xortl I'll add a note.

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer to your updated one, as it is more complete.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your file is utf8 encoded you could do something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{sverb}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2190}{$\leftarrow$}
\begin{document}

\verbinput{arrowfile.txt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding your line `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` renders all the arrows.

Comment: @Xortl It depends on your latex version if you need \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} or not. In a current system it is not longer needed as it is the default and then egreg's code works too.

Comment: This doesn't use the monospaced font for the arrow.